# how to organize models used by backend and frontend in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails application with a frontend for users and a configuration interface for the editing team. 
Both interfaces are really different but they use the same DB and the same models. Following the "everything slim but the fat controllers" philosophy models have accumulated methods used by both the backend and the frontend as well as independent methods.

For instance there are some constants in the Product model used by both but a self.find_by_week_logs(week_id) used only by the backend or a  self.deliveries_per_page (pid) used only by the frontend.

How should I best organize this?

I so far thought or 3 possible solutions but I think they are not good enough.

- Just put everything in the model and don't worry about this
- Organize as :

> ```
> class Product < Activerecod:Base
>   common stuff
>   # Frontend 
>   Front end stuff
>   # Backend 
>   Back end stuff
> end
> ```

- Organize as:

> class Product < Activerecod:Base
>
> ```
>  common stuff
>  module Frontend 
>    module ClassMethods
>      Frontend stuff
>    end
>    Frontend stuff
>   end
>   module Backend 
>    module ClassMethods
>      Backend stuff
>    end
>    Backend stuff
>   end
>   include Backend
>   extend Bancked::ClassMethods
>
> end
> ```

Any other solution/idea?

Answer (score 1):

create folders with the model name in `app/models`, here it's `app/models/products`

extract front end related codes to `app/models/products/front_end.rb`:
you can use [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) to help:

```
module Product::FrontEnd
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module InstanceMethods
    ...
  end
  module ClassMethods
    ...
  end
end
```

then in `products.rb`:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include FrontEnd
end
```

Comment: This will create lots of directories for maybe the wrong purpose. Even creating a Frontend directory would be weird I think

Comment: I'm confused on your comment jordi.  I think putting modules in the models directories makes more sense some cases than in the lib folder.  I think it is a good way to extract stuff that could be reused by models but has a Product context like product statuses, validations..etc  Thoughts?